# Eloquent model event `updating` isn't firing in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm trying to catch the model event `updating` in laravel 7 but it doesn't fire.

This is the place where the model get's changed:

```
public function update(Request $request, Model $model)  {
  $model->update($request->input());

  return new Resource($model);
}
```

I also tried this to update the values:

```
public function update(Request $request, Model $model)  {
  $model->attribute1 = $request->get('value1');
  $model->attribute2 = $request->get('value2');
  $model->attribute3 = $request->get('value3');
  $model->save();

  return new Resource($model);
}
```

And here I'm trying to catch the event within the bill model:

```
protected static function boot() {
  static::updating(function ($model) {
      // code
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're actually changing data on the model. If the model isn't dirty when you save, Laravel doesn't actually call the update functionality, or fire the updating/updated events.

Comment: Yes, I‘m sure that the model is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `parent::boot()` at the start of your boot method:

```
protected static function boot() {

  parent::boot();

  static::updating(function ($model) {
      // code
  });
}
```

Laravel 7 added a booted method to make it easier:

[Adding booting / booted methods to Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/ef26dbfa30ae77f76612aa55e0812be693033092)

> Currently, users who extend the boot method to add event listeners on
>   model events must remember to call parent::boot() at the start of
>   their method (or after). This is often forgotten and causes confusion
>   for the user. By adding these simple place-holder extension points we
>   can point users towards these methods instead which do not require
>   them to call any parent methods at all.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events-using-closures):

> Instead of using custom event classes, you may register Closures that
>   execute when various model events are fired. Typically, you should
>   register these Closures in the booted method of your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\AgeScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($user) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```